# Combining multiple netcdf in folder in R

Tags: r, netcdf

I have a folder that contains 61 netcdf files containing 4 dimension (lat, lon, time and depth) and 9 variables.

I would like to combine all the files in the folder to one netcdf file with the variable "`thetao`" so that the 4 other dimensions remain.

I do not have a lot of background in R. So far I have come to this from what I have gathered from other sources:

```
library(ncdf4)
library(raster)

# Set working directory
setwd("C:/Users/L1586/Downloads/CMEMS_2015/05/BAL-HBM_PHY-201505-DailyMeans/")

# Declare data frame
df = NULL

#Open all files
files = list.files("C:/Users/L1586/Downloads/CMEMS_2015/05/BAL-HBM_PHY-201505-DailyMeans/",pattern='*.nc',full.names=TRUE)

# Loop over files
for(i in seq_along(files)) {
  nc = nc_open(files[i])
}
```

Comment: are all the netcdfs on the same dimensions? will 'thetao' represent something related to the original file?

Comment: Also, is time the dimension you will combine on? And, is it already the unlimited dimension? Can you provide the results of print(nc) for the first file. I think the best answer here for R would be "get a copy of the first file with only thetao variable and with time as the unlimited dimension, and then bind each other files's thetao into that. It's a big hassle in R really, and you'd be better doing it at the command line (but that's also a hassle, and even more so on Windows). In R from scratch you'll have to learn about ncdf4 for defining or copying dimensions and attributes in a new file.

Comment: I think getting a ".cdf" (text description) of the file is the best way, you can hack at that to get the basic starting structure. I don't know of any prior examples using R for this though.

Comment: May be this is off topic, because it addresses not a R solution. Merging and concatenig  NETCDF ensembles and records  is often reflected topic in "modelling comunity". You could several tools to do that like: NCO - ncecat/ncrcat (http://nco.sourceforge.net/nco.html#ncecat-netCDF-Ensemble-Concatenator), NCL (https://www.ncl.ucar.edu/Applications/addfiles.shtml) or CDO (http://hannahlab.org/cdo-extracting-a-variable-across-several-files/)

Comment: Another potential off-topic solution might be using TDS/THREDDS.  You could then aggregate the 61 files in-situ with NCML without creating a new file, and then use the aggregated dataset through a DAP-aware netcdf tools.   I use this for large multi-file datasets.